# domain = AVFoundationErrorDomain , code = -11828

Tags: ios, react-native, avfoundation, react-native-video, amazon-cloudfront

I am using the streaming url from CloudFront.

Sample URL:
https://d14nt81hc5bide.cloudfront.net/qyYj1PcUkYg2ALDfzAdhZAmb

On Android , it is working fine but in iOS it says:
domain = AVFoundationErrorDomain , code = -11828

From apple doc the error code 11828 is AVErrorFileFormatNotRecognized.
The media could not be opened because it is not in a recognized format.

Can someone suggest how to fix this error?

Comment: Did you try with another video? That URL doesn't seem to play anything for me, maybe it's indeed in a unrecognized format / corrupt.

Comment: @mihai1990 play with vlc media player it runs

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a video. It's actually a mp3 audio. I guess it could be caused by missing .mp3 extension in the URL.

Comment: that's the problem.... but cloudfront is not giving me .mp3 extension .. do you have knowledge about how to get .mp3 extension from cloudfront url ? @mihai1990

Comment: I don't know about that, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no other option but to make my CloudFront URL to have `.mp3` attached.
And then it works for ios.

Answer (score 1):

AVFoundation can be picky if an URL or the header of the response does not contain information about container format of the media (`mp4`,`mov`,...), which is the case here (no 'file extension' in the URL, and no content type in the response header).
Other media libraries and players seem to willing to just start loading and then guess the format by inspecting the incoming data, which is probably why they work in this case.

Unfortunately, to my knowledge at least, there is no (reliable) way to tell AVFoundation programmatically the format to expect and go ahead with that.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, This Error rise because [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation?language=objc) can not recognize your media format.

Try to [declare your mime type](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=36927) when upload media files to server

More about mime type [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)

> more info: [AWS streaming media content tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/vi/cloudfront/streaming/)